# Iterating through and updating JSON files in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a directory with JSON files that all have the same structure. I would like to loop through them and replace the values of key 'imgName' with the basename of the filename + 'png'. I managed to do that, however, when I dump the content of my dictionaries in the JSON files, they are empty. I'm sure there is some problem with the logic of my loops, but I can't figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
distorted_json = glob.glob('...')

for filename in distorted_json:
    with open(filename) as f:
        json_content = json.load(f)
        basename = os.path.basename(filename)
        if basename[-9:] == '.min.json':
            name = basename[0:-9]
            for basename in json_content:
                json_content['imgName'] = name + '.png'

for filename in distorted_json:
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dumps(json_content)
```

Thank you very much in advance for any advice!

Comment: Why are using 2 seperate loops rather than 1 common loop?

Comment: Thank you very much! That was easier than I had expected! I found another mistake: the "with open(filename, 'w') as f:" statement has to be within the loop. But thanks, now everything is working as it should :)

Comment: Instead of doing `basename[-9:] == '.min.json': name = basename[0:-9]`, I think you could have created a suffix variable (`suffix = ".min.json"`), and then, used this variable to do the other 2 operations, such as... `if basename.endswith(suffix): name = basename[0:len(suffix)]`. That way, you only need to change the suffix variable, and your program would still work as intended. :)

Comment: Thanks for the good tip! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `json.dump`, that is used to dump to a file, `json.dump(json_content, f)`. Also remove the second loop and move the contents to the previous loop.

```
for filename in distorted_json:
    with open(filename) as f:
        json_content = json.load(f)
        basename = os.path.basename(filename)
        if basename[-9:] == '.min.json':
            name = basename[0:-9]
            for basename in json_content:
                json_content['imgName'] = name + '.png'
                
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(json_content, f)
```